# javascript: unable to get value of the property

Tags: javascript

As you can see:

[image]

`t` is an object, but if I cast `t.datamax` - I get `undefined`: What is that, and how to deal with it?

Comment: Could the object have been mutated between when you observed it and when you attempted to read the `datamax` property?

Comment: @Pointy `type in console` - trying to see it's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an Array. Use index `0`.

```
t[0].datamax;
```